# Use Camera in Cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-plugins, camera, cordova-plugins

I am building a cordova app. it supports two platform (ios and Android). In this i have to show a camera in given frame of the app. Below the frame of camera, there will be a button named "Click". When i click this button, the currently showing things in camera should be captured and saved to gallery. Also there should be a slide bar on the left of camera. using this slider, one can zoom in or zoom out the camera.

Currently i have tried "org.apache.cordova.camera" http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.camera. But, i don't know how to present camera in a given frame. It is invoking the default camera app and the camera is opening in full screen. Please suggest me some another plugin or any Method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about displaying in a frame, but typically when you use the camera plugin it fires into the native camera effectively leaving you're app until the user either exits or takes a picture. It is at that stage you can handle the response data.

So for example, you would have a button, link or whatever when clicked you call something like the code below. You can then on the onSuccess callback load the image into a dynamically created canvas or something like that.

```html
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { 
 quality            : 40,
 destinationType    : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
 encodingType       : Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
 targetWidth        : 1600,
 targetHeight       : 1200,
 sourceType         : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
 correctOrientation : true
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... but that is not the requirements.. Let me update my question for better understanding...

Answer (score 1):

The camera plugin only starts the native camera app and gets the picture.

If you want something specific like what you describe, I'm affraid you may have to develop a native plugin for each platform.

Or you can try with HTML5 (for android it will work only for recent devices, maybe >4.2?) 
Raymond Camden made a blog entry about this : http://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/5/20/Capturing-camerapicture-data-without-PhoneGap
Or you can check the page on HTML5Rocks : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/
But I don't think you'll be able to zoom using HTML5.